# CASE statement within a REPLACE statement in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, replace, case

I have 3 variables which will be conditional when `@path` is not NULL i.e
`@serverName,@analysisDB,@cubeName`. Hence I used a `CASE` statement in the above `SELECT` statement. Similarly, for `@path` is not NULL the `@cubename` also needs to be conditional for `LVL5.L5_CubeName` (see `REPLACE` statement) but its inside a `REPLACE` statement and the `CASE` block becomes too complicated for the same. How do I write it if I want to do something like

```
CASE WHEN @path!='' THEN @cubeName ELSE LVL5.L5_CubeName in the REPLACE statement
SELECT LVL5.L5_Id,        
         CASE WHEN @path!='' THEN @serverName ELSE LVL5.L5_ServerName END [AnalysisServer],        
         CASE WHEN @path!='' THEN @analysisDB ELSE LVL5.L5_AnalysisDatabase END [AnalysisDatabase],        
         REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LVL5.L5_MDXQuery,'@@Level1',ISNULL(@lvl1DataVal,'')),    
         '@@Level2',ISNULL(@lvl2DataVal,'')),'@@CubeName',ISNULL(@cubeName,'')) [MDXQuery],         
         LVL5.L5_ReplaceMDX [ReplaceMDX],      
         LVL5.L5_RefreshDate [RefreshDate],      
         LVL5.L5_ReportAttribute [ReportAttribute],      
         LVL5.L5_ReportTitle [ReportTitle]           
  FROM   Report_SR_Level5 [LVL5]                  
  WHERE L4_ID = @L4_ID ORDER BY LVL5.L5_DisplayOrder
```

Comment: Please format you question to make is readable easily.  You might find it easy but it's hard I think for others to understand what you want. Also it might be easier if you used a simpler example rather than pasting your complex code (for example you might not LVL5.L5_ all over the sample)

Comment: yeah i know but i accidently hit the post button and now it wont let me do that before 20 mins

Comment: Not sure if I have understood your question properly? What happened when you run this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CASE WHEN @path is not null or @path != '' 
THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LVL5.L5_MDXQuery,'@@Level1',
ISNULL(@lvl1DataVal,'')),'@@Level2',ISNULL(@lvl2DataVal,'')),'@@CubeName',
ISNULL(@cubeName,'')) [MDXQuery]
ELSE Somethingelse END cubedata
```